# Teamcity pass kubernetes service account key with configuration parameter not working

Tags: kubernetes, teamcity, devops, service-accounts

I want to authenticate Kubernetes service account from Teamcity parameter passing.

I have configured teamcity configuration parameter like this:
[image]

I am trying to pass it through the echo command:
[image]

but it only dump the file to terminal instead of writing inside the file:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

`$%gcloudkey%` tries to search for bash variable with the name that equals to the value of `%gcloudkey%` TeamCity variable. That's what the `bad substitution` message is about. Try `"%gcouldkey%"` instead